# Tools for analyzing application perfomance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, logging

We have application deployed on customer's server where we haven't any access. 
Only thing which we can to do ask someone to make trivial operations(use profiler is not trivial operation) and change our code to add logger for example.

So i want to know is there any good logger specialized on perfomance. I know about log4net but it is just log some information. It would be good to get reports with charts and represent measures of code in hierachical view. I want logger which separate requests from different users. Ofcourse i can write it by myself but maybe there are exists some good free tools?

Comment: You want too much I think :)

Comment: This article might be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you have no access, the only solution I know is: http://miniprofiler.com/

Other ideas:

1. Ants profiler
2. NewRelic
3. Custom Attributes with PostSharp
4. List item
5. Custom ASP.NET MVC filters

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just logging you may want to think about using an application analytics tool. There are a variety of them available, many with a free usage tier. Depending on the tool you may need to do just a little extra coding to get the measurement data you want or it may require more significant custom coding.

First, one that I have personal experience with is [Loupe](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/See/Default.aspx) from Gibraltar Software. This is a logging and analytics tool that started as a logging tool and I think will give you more of what you want with minimal code changes.

The other option I am familiar with is [PreEmptive Analytics](http://www.preemptive.com/pa). This originated as an application analytics tool so you need to do a bit more coding to report on the more raw performance value data.

There are also other options in the .NET space including [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/), [Loggr](http://loggr.net/), [Equatec](http://www.telerik.com/analytics), and [Trackerbird](http://www.trackerbird.com/) that should all work with either a greater or lesser amount of custom coding for your situation.